# Spark dataframes: does it come in to spark sql or spark streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Does the concept of spark dataframes come into Spark SQL or Spark Streaming. Traditionally dataframes seems to fall in to Spark SQL. But,
correct me if wrong, dataframes seems to be able to handle live data too, so i got in to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Spark dataframe*s are suitable for both *spark batch processing* and *spark streaming processing*. *Spark dataframes* are *distributed* and *immutable* in nature, so you can't change it but create a new one from existing *dataframe*s. You can have more info in [Spark SQL, DataFrames and Datasets Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html)

And, *spark sql* is a concept where we write queries as in traditional databases like *mysql*. And *spark streaming* is a concept where *spark api*s are defined to deal with streaming data. So my point is that they are different concepts. You can differentiate between *batch processing* and *stream processing* in *spark* though.